# Move guide line after snapping object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, snapping

In Inkscape, I've placed a guide line. I've then snapped several objects to that line. I now want to move the guide line and have the objects move with it (since they are snapped). How can I do this? Right now, when I move the guide line either by dragging, or double clicking and changing values in guide line dialog, the line moves but the objects don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now the snapped objects cannot be moved with the guides. You can only do it by moving your guides and then snapping the objects to the guides. (Although there was a proposal on implementation of moving objects along with the guides, but it isn't implemented yet- http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/SpecGuidesImprovement)